# React Player plays video when a user is on the video section and pauses when not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, media-player, react-player

I want to achieve the feature when a user is in the video section React player will play the video and pause when the user leaves the section.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: **Not enough useful info**... Why is a simple `If` statement not enough here? What is  _"the video section"_ exactly, like is it a `<div>`, or is it an `<iframe>`, or is it an `.html` page? How does a user become _"in the video section"_? If you tell us the technical details (what things you got and what/where/how they do stuff in your code) then you'll get a faster Answer about playing video when user is in videos section..